# How to get the eventType from Esper configuration object at runtime

Tags: esper

I am running an application using Esper as my core CEP engine.
When I try to get the event type that I had previously registered with the Esper runtime, I get an UnsupportedOperationException.

```
esperConfiguration.addEventType(streamName, fieldNames, fieldTypes);

--------
//several lines later
--------

String[] propertyNames = esperConfiguration.getEventType(streamName).getPropertyNames();
```

I get the following exception:

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Obtaining an event type by name is only available at runtime
         at com.espertech.esper.client.Configuration.getEventType(Configuration.java:905)
```

I am not able to understand why my API call is not "at runtime", even when I am reusing the same object that I used for initializing the Esper engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EventType object is available on an initialized engine. So for example:

```
esperConfiguration.addEventType(streamName, fieldNames, fieldTypes);

EPServiceProvider epService = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(esperConfiguration);

String[] propertyNames = epService.getEPAdministrator().getConfiguration().getEventType(streamName).getPropertyNames();
```